# How to write and read the data in mifare card using python language

Tags: python, python-2.7, mifare

Can anyone let me know, how to read and write the data in Mifare 4k card using python language.

I am using Omnikey usb reader with mifare 4k card.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your in luck,

You can currently find a man at: http://rfidiot.org/ who has created a library of scripts for exactly your needs

```
"devices, such as the Omnikey CardMan are also supported. I am curently testing with a CardMan 5321"
```

You can find his Github account with the details:
https://github.com/AdamLaurie/RFIDIOt

This contains all the scripts you need to get started using your device with python, it would appear he has been working on this project since 2006 but I haven't looked at his code.

Give us and update if this gets you started!